# What are the $j$-invariants of the genus 1 modular curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I believe there are only finitely many congruence subgroups $\Gamma\le SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that the compactification of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ is genus 1.

Is there somewhere I can find a list of these genus 1 modular curves and look at their $j$-invariants (and ideally also reduction types over their field of definition). Here, I'm referring to the moduli-theoretic model of the elliptic curve, which is necessarily a quotient of some $X(n)$ (which is defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$) and hence the $j$-invariant will lie in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.

In particular I'm interested in whether or not you can say anything about the integrality of the $j$-invariants of these genus 1 modular curves, especially in the case when the congruence subgroup is torsion-free.

For example, are the $j$-invariants all integral? Do they all have additive/multiplicative reduction? Do they have CM?

Comment: For $\Gamma=\Gamma_0(N)$ you can read everything off from (the first few lines of) Cremona's tables. There will be other possibilities for $\Gamma$ though, I guess.

Comment: Note that specifying $\Gamma \leq SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ gives a curve $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ up to isomorphism over $\mathbb{C}$. This does not specify a $\mathbb{Q}$-structure on the curve. To do so, you need to choose an subgroup $\Gamma \leq GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ so that $\det : \Gamma \to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is surjective. For this reason, it is not immediately obvious to me that all of the $j$-invariants are rational, as (I'm pretty sure) that not all of the $\Gamma \leq SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ have models over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Not all integral ($X_0(27)$ is the Fermat cubic, with $j=0$), nor all non-integral (if $p\|N$ and $X_0(N)$ has genus $1$ then it has multiplicative reduction mod $p$ so there is a factor of $p$ in the denominator; example: $N=p=11$).

Comment: @JeremyRouse That's a good point. Here I mean the moduli-theoretic model. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Jeremy Rouse: you're quite right of course, but let me flag the following spanner which sometimes people throw in to add to the confusion. If $\Gamma$ is $\Gamma(N)$ ($N>2$) then using a full level $N$ structure in the $GL(2)$ theory of canonical models of course spits out a connected but geometrically disconnected curve, defined over $Q$ but whose geom irred components are defined over $Q(\zeta_N)$. However some people use $Y(N)$ to mean the moduli space of ell curve + symplectic full level $N$ structure, which is geom connected and does give a model for the quotient over $Q$. Urk.

Answer (score 5):

First, there is no comprehensive list of all models of modular curves of genus $1$. (There is a list of congruence subgroups of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ [here](http://www.uncg.edu/mat/faculty/pauli/congruence/csg1.html).) Many cases have been computed, including the $X_{0}(n)$, $X_{1}(n)$, $X(n)$, as well as many cases that have prime power level. (With David Zureick-Brown, I did all of the cases whose level is a power of $2$ that might have rational points. See our paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5997)). Another really handy tool is the code that David Zywina has written (see the paper [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~zywina/papers/PossibleIndices/PossibleIndices.pdf)) that will count points on any modular curve $X_{G}$ (provided $G \subseteq GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ has surjective determinant). This will allow one to determine the isogeny class of ${\rm Jac}~X_{G}$, but this is not quite enough to determine the $j$-invariant.

Based on the examples that are known, it is not clear to me there is a relationship between the integrality of the $j$-invariant and the torsion structure. Here are some examples:

$X_{0}(11): y^{2} + y = x^{3} - x^{2} - 10x - 20$, $j$-invariant is $-122023936/161051$ is not integral, but the subgroup $\Gamma_{0}(11)$ is torsion-free (well, its image in ${\rm PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is).

$X_{0}(17): y^{2} + xy + y = x^{3} - x^{2} - x - 14$, $j$-invariant is $-35937/83521$ is not integral, and the subgroup $\Gamma_{0}(17)$ is not torsion-free (because it has elliptic elements of order $2$).

$X_{0}(27): y^{2} + y = x^{3} - 7$, $j$-invariant is zero (and the curve is isomorphic to the Fermat cubic). The subgroup is torsion-free.

$X_{0}(49): y^{2} + xy = x^{3} - x^{2} - 2x - 1$, $j$-invariant is $-3375$ (and has CM by the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$). The subgroup is not torsion-free, as it contains elliptic elements of order $3$.

Many of these curves have CM. ($X_{0}(32)$, $X_{0}(36)$, $X_{0}(49)$, $X_{{\rm ns}}^{+}(11)$, $X(6)$, most, but not all of the $2$-power level genus $1$ curves.)

Comment: In your paper with DZB that you linked, in the first table, would you happen to know if the curves with non-integral $j$-invariant corresponded to torsion-free subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Didn't know of Pauli's list; thanks.  Might make a good project for a student  or a team of students to get explicit models and parametrizations of all these curves.

Comment: In reference to the paper with DZB, all the modular curves of genus $1$ that we compute models for have good reduction away from $2$, and all elliptic curves with good reduction away from $2$ have integral $j$-invariants.